# SwiftUI: ViewModel making app crash when loading a view

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I want to rename an item in a ForEach list. When i try to load the EditListView for a selected list the entire app crashes.

This is a SwiftUI macOS app and the items are saved using CoreData.

[image]

The crash happens as soon as you click on "Edit List" for any of the list items.

[image]

It doesn't crash if i remove this view model `var listVM: MyListViewModel` from the EditListViewModel.

Here's the EditListView

```
struct EditListView: View {
    let name: String
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    var list: MyListViewModel
    @ObservedObject var editListVM: EditListViewModel
   
    init(name: String,list: MyListViewModel, isVisible: Binding<Bool> ) {
        self.list = list
        editListVM = EditListViewModel(listVM: list)
        _isVisible = isVisible
        self.name = name
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Button(action: {
            editListItemVM.update()
            }) {
                Text("Update List Name")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
              self.isVisible = false
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
            }......
```

EditListViewModel

```
class EditListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var listVM: MyListViewModel
    @Published var name: String = ""
 
    
    init(listVM: MyListViewModel) {
        self.listVM = listVM
        name = listVM.name

        } 
        func update(){
          ....} 

  
}
```

MyListViewModel

```
struct MyListViewModel: Identifiable {
    
    private let myList: MyList
    
    init(myList: MyList) {
        self.myList = myList
    }
    
    var id: NSManagedObjectID {
        myList.objectID
    }
    
    var name: String {
        myList.name ?? ""
    }     
}
```

MyList Model

```
@objc(MyList)
public class MyList: NSManagedObject, BaseModel {
    
    static var all: NSFetchRequest<MyList> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<MyList> = MyList.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return request
    } 
    
}

extension MyList {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MyList> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MyList>(entityName: "MyList")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?


    }

extension MyList : Identifiable {

}
```

Here's the Main View

```
struct MyListsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: MyListsViewModel      
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false
    
    init(vm: MyListsViewModel) {
        _vm = StateObject(wrappedValue: vm)
    }             
            List {
                Text("My Lists")
                ForEach(vm.myLists) { myList in
                    
                    NavigationLink {
                        MyListItemsHeaderView(name: myList.name)
                                                  
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                                EditListView(name: myList.name, list: MyListViewModel(myList: MyList()), isVisible: $showPopover)
                                   }
                    }                                                                       
                    }.contextMenu {
                        Button {
                            showPopover = true
                            // Show the EditListView
                     
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit List", systemImage: "pen.circle")
                            
                        }......
```

Comment: `EditListView(name: myList.name, list: MyListViewModel(myList: MyList()), isVisible: $showPopover)`, why do you create a new instance of `MyList` every time the sheet is shown and where does MyList() come from, normally you use an init that takes an NSManagedObjectConntext as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First get rid of your view model objects we don't use those in SwiftUI. We use the View struct and the property wrappers like `@FetchRequest` make the struct behave like an object. It looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item)
```

I recommend looking at Xcode's app template with core data checked.

Then for editing you can use `.sheet(item:` like this:

```
struct ItemEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item // this is the scratch pad item
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss // causes body to run
    let onSave: () -> Void
    @State var errorMessage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                    Text(errorMessage)
                }
                Button("Update Time") {
                    item.timestamp = Date()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        // first save the scratch pad context then call the handler which will save the view context.
                        do {
                            try context.save()
                            errorMessage = nil
                            onSave()
                        } catch {
                            let nsError = error as NSError
                            errorMessage  = "Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemEditorConfig: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    let item: Item
    
    init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext, objectID: NSManagedObjectID) {
        // create the scratch pad context
        context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = viewContext
        // load the item into the scratch pad
        item = context.object(with: objectID) as! Item
    }
}

struct EditItemButton: View {
    let itemObjectID: NSManagedObjectID
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var itemEditorConfig: ItemEditorConfig?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: edit) {
            Text("Edit")
        }
        .sheet(item: $itemEditorConfig, onDismiss: didDismiss) { config in
            ItemEditor(item: config.item) {
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
                itemEditorConfig = nil // dismiss the sheet
            }
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, config.context)
        }
    }
    
    func edit() {
        itemEditorConfig = ItemEditorConfig(viewContext: viewContext, objectID: itemObjectID)
    }
    
    func didDismiss() {
        // Handle the dismissing action.
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditItemButton(itemObjectID: item.objectID)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the params for EditListView in the main view were incorrect.

Fixed it with the following params:

```
  .sheet(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                                EditListView(name: myList.name, list: myList, isVisible: $showPopover)
                                   }
```